# AdView causing 'Unimplemented webview method onkeydown' Logcat warning

Tags: android, opengl-es, webview, user-input

My app is an openGL app and I'm getting the following warning in Logcat.  It's Being caused by my AdView - Whenever I press my back key (or volume keys) the warning appears:

**unimplemented webview method onkeydown**

Is there something I can do to stop these warnings from appearing? And are they anything I should worry about?

Note: I've confirmed that the AdView is causing this.  I've temporarily removed it and the warning disappears.

This is my onCreate() method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Request full screen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Disable auto connect to play services
    getGameHelper().setMaxAutoSignInAttempts(0);

    adSize = AdSize.SMART_BANNER;

    //Create a displayMetrics object to get pixel width and height
    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    width = metrics.widthPixels;
    height = metrics.heightPixels;

    //Work out density of screen
    density = metrics.density * 160;    
    x = Math.pow(metrics.widthPixels / density, 2);
    y = Math.pow(metrics.heightPixels / density, 2);
    screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);

    if (screenInches > 8) { // > 728 X 90
        adSize = AdSize.LEADERBOARD;
    } else if (screenInches > 6) { // > 468 X 60
        adSize = AdSize.MEDIUM_RECTANGLE;
    } else { // > 320 X 50
        adSize = AdSize.BANNER;
    }

        // Create an ad.
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(adSize);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

        // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy.
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        // get test ads on a physical device.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
          .addTestDevice(deviceID) 
        .build();

        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        //Create splash-screen object and pass in scaled width and height
        splash = new SplashScreen(MainActivity.this, width, height);

        //Create dialog that will show splash-screen 
        loading_dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);

        //Set and display splash screen view
        loading_dialog.setContentView(splash);
        loading_dialog.show();

        //Create and set GL view (OpenGL View)
        myView = new MyGLSurfaceView(MainActivity.this);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

            //Set the colour as there is a bug
            adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            layout.addView(myView);
            layout.addView(adView, adParams);

        //Create a copy of the Bundle

        if (savedInstanceState != null){
            newBundle = new Bundle(savedInstanceState);         
        }

        //Create splash object and pass bundle
        //in onPostExecute
        DisplaySplash goSplash = new DisplaySplash(newBundle);
        goSplash.execute();

        //Set main renderer

        setContentView(layout);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it may be an issue in the framework itself: [Issue #68284](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68284)